# Azure pipeline runtime evaluated variable passed a parameter

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an AzurePowerShell script (powershell/gettenants.ps1) which sets the value of the tenants variable.

The following bash task successfully echos the new value BUT the following template recieves the default value (set at the top of the script). Note Im using expression syntax when specifying the template parameter value.

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

```
variables:
 tenants: "default value"

 - stage: Build_Shared_Update
   jobs:
   - job: Get_all_Tenants_Info
     pool:
       vmImage: 'windows-latest'
     steps:
       - checkout: self
         fetchDepth: 1
       - task: AzurePowerShell@4
         inputs:
           azureSubscription:  'Product Subscription(Guid)'
           targetType: 'filePath'
           scriptPath: powershell/gettenants.ps1
           errorActionPreference: 'stop' 
           azurePowerShellVersion: 'latestVersion'

       - task: Bash@3
         inputs:
           targetType: 'inline'
           script: echo $(tenants)
   - template: pipeline-templates/shared-infrastructure-plan.yml  # Template reference
     parameters:
       tenants: ${{variables.tenants}}
```

Inside the template the parameter is referenced like this:

```
-out=sharedplan -var=list_of_tenants=${{parameters.tenants}}
```

Comment: Can you show how you're setting the tenants variable in gettenants.ps1? This answer might be of interest, it has an example of how to set Azure DevOps output variable from powershell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56980502/azure-devops-azure-powershell-task-output-variable#56980600

Comment: write-host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=tenants]$result"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables werent in scope!

Its worth noting that "much to learn" also identified this :)

Comment: So, did you get a working solution... what was it?
I'm still stuck fighting combintions of syntax and scope, trying to solve something similar, getting nowhere.

Comment: Yeah (although looking at our code in prod its now very different). However in the specific case here my issue was the variable was job scoped and I needed to use the  isOutput property so it was available to later jobs

Answer (score 1):

when using `${{ }}` syntax that variable is being replace at the compile time.

Read more here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax

Comment: Ok... so if I change ${{variables.tenants}} to $(tenants)  the template stick recieves the default value. The bash script stills sees the correct value

Comment: I've just noticed indentation, template is on a job level and creating variable is only job scoped, if you want to create variable and have it available in downstream jobs you need to add isOutput property  [AzureDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable), if you make template as a next step after bash it should work with $(tenants)

Comment: Hey - yeah I realised it was a scoping issue. I then realised that the job could easily be a task... :)